# Why is the intersection of four generic cubics in $\mathbb{P}^2$ six points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, cubics, blowup

I read today that a cubic surface can be constructed by blowing up 6 points in general position on $\mathbb{P}^2$. The crux of the proof depends on the fact that taking four general cubics $f_1,\ldots,f_4$, they give a rational morphism $\mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^3$ by
$$
[x:y:z] \mapsto [f_1([x:y:z]): \cdots : f_4([x:y:z])]
$$
why do these four polynomials have a vanishing locus of six points? **Also**, how does this generalize to other degree/dimensional varieties? This may be a really nice avenue for computing chow rings.

Comment: Don't you want to pick 6 points (no 3 of which are collinear) and consider the cubics passing through them? Then compute the dimension of this linear system.

Comment: If that's the case, how can I count the number of cubics passing through these points?

Comment: The dimension of the vector space of cubics is 10 and passing through six general points gives you six linear conditions to get you a four dimensional vector space.

Comment: @Mohan, six independent conditions, of course.

Comment: So if I pick five points on $\mathbb{P}^2$ in general position, I will get a rational map to $\mathbb{P}^4$ whose image is a cubic surface?

Comment: @user251222: no, in that case the image has degree 4.

Comment: @Nefertiti, why is that true? Where do I learn this from?

Comment: The degree of the image is the number of intersection points on the blow-up surface of the proper transforms of two general cubics through your five points. Two general cubics in $\mathbf P^2$ meet in 9 points, so if you blow up 5 points, you are left with 4 intersection points. I am not sure where you can read this stuff written in a nice way. There is a lot of information in the book _Classical Algebraic Geometry_ by Dolgachev, but in my opinion it is not so nicely written for beginners. There is also the book _Cubic Forms_ by Manin, which I think treats this material, but again maybe...

Comment: ...not at a good level. (IIRC the first chapter is a seemingly weird digression on commutative Moufang loops.) There are a couple of standard references on algebraic surfaces (by Beauville and Badescu). I haven't read either, but maybe they talk about these things too.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that a genral quartuple of cubic polynomials has 6 common zero points. In fact, they have none, and this can be easily seen geometrically.

Consider the triple Veronese (= anticanonical) embedding $v_3:P^2 \to  P^9$. Then a choice of 4 cubic polynomials on $P^2$ is equivalent to a choice of 4 linear functions on $P^9$, i.e., to a choice of a $P^5 \subset P^9$. The zero locus of the polynomials is the intersection $v_3(P^2) \cap P^5$ in $P^9$ and it is empty for a general $P^5$ by dimension reasons.

On the other hand, if you want to get the situation, corresponding to a cubic surface, you can act as follows. Choose a general point on $S_9 = v_3(P_2)$ and let $S_8$ be its projection from this point. Then choose a general point on $S_8$ and let $S_7$ be its projection, e.t.c. The sequence $S_9 \subset P^9$, $S_8 \subset P^8$, \dots, $S_3 \subset P^3$ is a sequence of (anticanonically embedded) del Pezzo surfaces of the corresponding degrees. The surface $S_d$ is isomorphic to the blowup of a general set of $9-d$ points on $P^2$.